How to get in C# a general date value like the general format in Excel from a date:time value (ex 2024-12-11 0:12 to 45637.0084722222)
When I move a date:time value in an Excel sheet, such as 2024-12-11 12:12:12 AM, to a general format cell I get something like 45637.0084722222. I need to obtain something similar in a C# application, where from a date value I generate the equivalent of what an Excel cell with a general format would store, something like 45637.0084722222. How can I achieve it?

Look at the DateTime.ToOADate() method:
var dt = new DateTime(2024, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToOADate());

Result:
45637.508472222224
See it here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/r5vUqR

The "OA" in ToOADate() stands for "OLE Automation", which is what Excel is using.

I found the below way to get the OA equivalent:
DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;
originalDateTB.Text = aDate.ToString();
convertedDateTB.Text = aDate.ToOADate().ToString();


Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful. - From Review

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine: While they obviously learned from the previous answers, they took a different approach to constructing the time in this code. I’d consider this more than just a “thank you” answer.

I wouldn't call this a different approach, it's still just calling .ToOADate(). Adding context that was missing from the question really shouldn't count.

As far as I know Excel stores that value as floating-point number from their epoch which is 1st of January 1900 you need to calc the days since them and include the fractional part of the current day.

There's a caveat where Excel actually starts on Dec 31 of 1899, but then skips a day on March 1 to catch up again, in order to maintain compatibility with a bug in old Lotus notes (there is no day 60)

Thats an intresting blog articel. But just so I understood it correctly. Lotus is bugged, excel fixed that with another sloppy workaround they had to do. But the theoretical counting from 1900-01-01 should work ?

Pretty much, as long as your dates are after March 1, 1900.
